# Button pushes down background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this html page

```
  <body>

  <a href="app.html" class="btn btn-primary go">Go</a>

  </body>
```

which has a background image

```
<style>

     html { 
  background: url(img/mobile.fw.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
    }
    .go{
    z-index:1 !important;
    margin-top:40%;
    }
    </style>
```

The problem with my page is that it pushes down the background image when i have the button like the way i do. How can i have the button not push down the background?.

Comment: Probably the effect of _collapsing margins_. Try a different way to move the button to the position where you want it - for example relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me. i tested it

```css
     html { 
 background: url(https://images7.alphacoders.com/602/thumb-1920-602691.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
    }
    .go{
    z-index:1 !important;
    margin-top:40%;
    }
```

```html
 <body>

  <a href="app.html" class="btn btn-primary go">Go</a>

  </body>
```

Comment: I added the css framework in use in the tags section.

Comment: @mongodb what do you mean? you added code to a different portion of the button? cause if so do add that to the post

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.go{
  
  margin-top:40%;
  background: white;
  border: solid 2px black;
}
```

```html
 <body>

  <button href="app.html" class="btn btn-primary go">Go</button>
```

Hope it helps